# Get week of the year from datetime series with leading zeros

Tags: python, pandas, date, series

```
0     2022-02-16
1     2022-01-05
2     2021-12-08
3     2021-12-08
4     2021-12-08
         ...    
995   2021-12-08
996   2021-12-08
997   2021-12-08
998   2022-01-05
999   2021-12-24
Name: START_DATE, Length: 1000, dtype: datetime64[ns]
```

From this pandas serie I want to get the number of the week on the format XX (01 through 53, including leading zeros).

I've tried `df['START_DATE'].dt.isocalendar().week.astype(str).str.zfill(2)` which gives me the correct output, but I was wondering if there was a cleaner way of doing it.

Thanks

Comment: This looks clean to me

Comment: Since `df.START_DATE.dt.weekofyear` is deprecated and raises a `FutureWarning`, your solution is the best you can do.

Comment: Wow, thank you I thought it might be a more direct Pythonic way of doing it... Thanks

Answer (score 0):

This should do it:

```
df['START_DATE'].dt.strftime('%W')
```

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).